# SWT - Remove Focus from Button/Control in Shell

Tags: java, button, focus, swt

I have a window that contains a few buttons (the window acts as a starting page). When I first create and open the `Shell`, the first `Button` created is assigned the focus. Is there a way to remove the focus from this `Button`?

Using `SWT.NO_FOCUS` does not help.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of creating dummy/unnecessary button You can just focus your shell:

```
shell.open();
shell.forceFocus();
```

This do the trick at least in gtk.

Comment: Works on Windows as well.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the easiest work around to this is by using the following steps:

1. Create a dummy button that doesn't do anything
2. Assign the focus to that button
3. Hide it (position it so it can't be seen)

This is most easily done if you are using a `FormLayout`:

```
Button dummy = new Button(parent, SWT.PUSH)
dummy.setFocus()
FormData data = new FormData();
data.bottom = new FormAttachment(-1);
dummy.setLayoutData(data);
```

This is assuming the parent `Composite`'s `clientArea` takes up the entire  window, or is positioned at the top.

### Full working example

```
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.FillLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.FormAttachment;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.FormData;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.FormLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Button;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;

public class SOClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Display d = new Display();
        Shell shell = new Shell(d);
        shell.setSize(500, 500);
        shell.setText("Remove focus from first button");

        shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());

        Composite comp = new Composite(shell, SWT.NONE);
        comp.setLayout(new FormLayout());

        int style = SWT.PUSH | SWT.BORDER;
        Button b1 = new Button(comp, style);
        Button b2 = new Button(comp, style);

        b1.setText("Button 1");
        //position: top, spanning the majority of the windows width
        FormData b1Data = new FormData();
        b1Data.top = new FormAttachment(0, 5);
        b1Data.left = new FormAttachment(0, 5);
        b1Data.right = new FormAttachment(100, -5);
        b1.setLayoutData(b1Data);

        b2.setText("Button 2");
        //position: under b1, spanning the majority of the windows width
        FormData b2Data = new FormData();
        b2Data.top = new FormAttachment(b1, 5);
        b2Data.left = new FormAttachment(0, 5);
        b2Data.right = new FormAttachment(100, -5);
        b2.setLayoutData(b2Data);

        //try removing/commenting this section to see the effect
        Button dummy = new Button(comp, style);
        dummy.setFocus();
        FormData dummyData = new FormData();
        dummyData.bottom = new FormAttachment(-1);
        dummy.setLayoutData(dummyData);

        shell.open();

        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if(!d.readAndDispatch())
                d.sleep();
        }
        d.dispose();
    }

}
```

### Why does this work?

The dummy button is still usable, you are still able to click it (physically and programmatically), but it isn't visible, so to the user it  looks like a button wasn't assigned focus.

`Button.setVisible(false)` does not work for this - The button is recognized by SWT as hidden and SWT therefore looks for the next button to give focus to.

If you need to remove focus on any of the buttons again, you can simply use `dummy.setFocus()`

Answer (score 0):

```
Button button=new Button(shell, SWT.PUSH);
button.setVisible(false); // hide & avoid focus
shell.setDefaultButton(button);
```